# In python: how to use descriptor to simulate the property

Tags: python

Recently,I am reading the book 《learning python》.In this book, it uses descriptor to simulate the property as follow:

```
class Property:
    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
      self.fget = fget
      self.fset = fset
      self.fdel = fdel # Save unbound methods
      self.__doc__ = doc # or other callables
    def __get__(self, instance, instancetype=None):
      if instance is None:
         return self
      if self.fget is None:
         raise AttributeError("can't get attribute")
      return self.fget(instance) # Pass instance to self
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
      if self.fset is None:
         raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
      self.fset(instance, value)
    def __delete__(self, instance):
      if self.fdel is None:
          raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
      self.fdel(instance)
```

At last,it says "...we’d have to extend our Property class with setter and deleter methods, which would save the decorated accessor function and return the property object (self should suffice). Since the property built-in already does this, we’ll omit a formal coding of this extension here." 
My question is how to realize the "setter" decorator and "deleter" decorator?I have no idea

Comment: Maybe try something first before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add methods to your `Property` class:

```
class Property:
    ...
    def setter(self, f):
        self.fset = f
        return self

    def deleter(self, f):
        self.fdel = f
        return self
```

These simply take functions and alter the corresponding attribute of `Property`.  These can then be used as eg

```
class some_thing(object):
    @Property
    def some_property(self):
        ...

    @some_property.setter
    def set_some_property(self, x):
        ...

    @some_property.deleter
    def del_some_property(self):
        ...
```